# How to delete files when a record is deleted?

Tags: mysql

I have a table:

```
CREATE TABLE photo (
    photo_id BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    property_id BIGINT NOT NULL,
    filename VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL;
    ...
    PRIMARY KEY (photo_id),
    CONSTRAINT photo_fk_property FOREIGN KEY (property_id)
        REFERENCES property (property_id)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

When a row from this table is deleted, the file that is referenced by it should be deleted as well. There are two scenarios when records are deleted from this table:

1. User deletes one particular photo.
2. User deletes one particular property object (as in "real estate property"), and all the photos referencing that property are deleted automatically by `ON DELETE CASCADE`.

I know I can select all the referenced photos in the database before deleting a property and delete them along with their files one by one, but I'm looking for an alternate solution. Is it possible to catch the moment when a record in the `photo` table is deleted and delete the file automatically, without resigning the `CASCADE` clause, maybe in a trigger somehow?

Comment: A trigger can do actions on the DB in the moment of a `delete`. But for file deletion outside the DB you have to do that by yourself.

Comment: I don't think that would be possible. the same problem was raised [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6527514/delete-file-using-mysql-procedure)

Comment: It's possible trough a user defined function called sys_exec, but I wouldn't recommend it. You should control this behaviour trough the language that makes your app run, database should only handle its data, not the files as well.

Comment: @Septagram: Can we delete/create files from within mysql? I'm not challenging you, but really would like to know.
But, you can surely delete the files from with in the Programming language you are using in the code at server side.

Comment: @N.B., you are probably right. While DocJones answers the general question, in this particular situation it will be cleaner to delete files outside of the database. I shall replace `ON DELETE CASCADE` with `ON DELETE SET NULL` and after deleting a `property`, I would select all the dangling `photo` records and delete all of them, to make sure no dangling files are left. Thanks to everyone :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are looking for a [DELETE TRIGGER](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/triggers.html). See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/668666/when-a-new-row-in-database-is-added-an-external-command-line-program-must-be-in) for a similar Problem & Solution. External action can be achieved via installation of [sys_exec](https://github.com/mysqludf/lib_mysqludf_sys).

```
CREATE TRIGGER foobar
AFTER DELETE ON photo
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   CALL sys_exec(concat('/bin/rm -f ',filename));
END
```

Comment: And if the delete were a transaction, what would happen? I can't undelete files if I have to rollback. And will transactions fail, if the file deletion has a problem? - Say permission problems.

Comment: link is not valid for sys_exec

Comment: linked github repo against sys_exec-link